# Does hiding in dead bodies work against enemies?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

Just curious if dead bodies are client-side or server-side. I've seen plenty of youtube videos where players attempt to hide amongst corpses in order to fool  enemies searching the area but not once can I recall if those corpses only show up on your screen or show up for everyone on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bodies are client-side rendered.

There are lots of rants about them and also barricade debris for the entire existence of Siege (dates are as late as early 2019). For example, here is reddit thread: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/7oide9/clientside_dead_bodies_a_brief_rant/

Here is another one from Ubisoft forums, where community manager seems to admit the issue:
https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1867443-Client-side-bodies-and-issues-with-it